# AudioQueue read input volume

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, input, volume

I'm on OS X, and i've to read continuously input volume while i speak (like Siri that shows purple bar high or low for powerful voice or weak voice).
I've tried this code but it returns me "parameter ID invalid":

```
    UInt32 size = sizeof(AudioQueueLevelMeterState) * record_state.data_format.mChannelsPerFrame;
    AudioQueueLevelMeterState *outValue = malloc(size);
OSStatus errorMsg = AudioQueueGetProperty (record_state.queue, kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter,  &outValue, &size     );

    if (!errorMsg) {
        printf("Volume: %f", outValue[0].mPeakPower);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Er: %i", errorMsg);
    }
```

How can i do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable the metering by setting `kAudioQueueProperty_EnableLevelMetering` property? If not, that could be the cause.

Comment: No, i don't. Where should i do this?

Comment: Just after you init your audio queue, after you set the stream description for example.

Comment: Ok, done. It doesn't go in the else block, but it crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) here:
printf("Volume: %f", outValue[0].mPeakPower);